# How to set a TeamCity build trigger to use an environment parameter

Tags: build, parameters, triggers, teamcity

I have a TeamCity environment parameter (env.Environment) that can be set to the particular environment you can run the build against i.e. UAT, DEV

During TeamCity Build triggers setup, there are no options to select the parameters you want the triggered build to run against. When I run the build manually, I get the option to select the parameters to run against but not when setting a trigger, any ideas where/how this can be set?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple workarounds to achieve it but you cannot implement this directly in the TeamCity triggers.

1. The environment that you have created just change the display value to "Prompt" in the specs. But I believe it will pause the build. So whenever the build gets triggered on the scheduled time then you need to select value in the prompt.
2. The most efficient way that I could think of is trigger the build with the help of TC rest API. In the request payload, you can send the desired parameter value as well. So whatever the condition is just handle those things in the custom script written in any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

one more (not really beautiful) way - when build started by trigger, teamcity parameter `teamcity.build.triggeredBy.username` is equals `"Schedule Trigger"`

so you can check its value in first step of build in command line and then redefine needed params

```
if [ %teamcity.build.triggeredBy.username% == "Schedule Trigger" ]; then
  echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.PARAM' value='VALUE']"
fi
```